# SQL Server - store datetime and decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, decimal

I'm developing a change history table where I'll basically record the old and new value for changes in fields of two types: decimal and datetime.

To make it simple, I was thinking about create a string field and convert the values to string before store in the table. 
My problem is that later I'll have to create a field in the report to show the difference between the changes (like if the date as changed from 01/20/2015 to 01/27/2015 the difference will be 7 and so on). I do not want to create a field in the table to record the difference between the fields, I want to do it in the report side.

My question is:
Is there any way to store those two kind of data (decimal and datetime) to make it simple to do comparisons later? Cause if I have it in string type I'll have to convert it two times - one before create the record in DB and the other to see what is the difference between them.

Comment: You can easily `CAST(stringfield AS DATE)` on the tail-end, but I don't follow why you don't want to use a `DATE` field.

Comment: And why not to store in history the real types of those columns??

Comment: If you are storing dates, use the appropriate data type, it is `DATE` or `DATETIME`  it will allow you to use built-in DATETIME functions and will make your life easier. You have made the good choice of not storing the difference between values, it is something you should do at run time.

Comment: The problem in storing it in a datetime field is because I have decimal fields to store as well. I'll create a new record for every field change, so if someone change the price and the date at same time, it will create two records in my table. 
If I create a datetime field I'll have to create decimal fields as well and there will be 2 fields that I'll not use in my records - if I store decimal I'll not use the datetime fields and if I store datetime I'll not use the decimal ones.

Comment: @IohannOro, man make history table the copy of your table and store columns in appropriate columns in history table, not in ONE column!

Comment: I know it is not the best thing to do - store two types of data in one field, but if there is any way to do it, it will save a lot a time later on (:

Comment: It will not save yur time, it will become your pain later

Comment: Actually, it *may* save you some time at first, but has the potential to make your life a living hell later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best approach would be what I like to call the *never delete, never update approach*.
Basically, you add a column to your source table for the record status, that can be either `current`, `historic` or `deleted` (Use a tinyint for that, just be sure to have it linked to a row status table for readability). then instead of deleting a record you update it's status to deleted, and instead of updating it, you change it's status to historic and then insert a new record with the new data.

Naturally, this approach has it's price, since you will have to write an instead of update trigger, but that is a small price to pay comparing to other approaches of keeping history data.
Also, if your primary key is not an `identity` column, you will need to add this column to your primary key (and any other unique constraints you might have).
You also might want to add a filter to your non-clustered indexes so that they will only index the records where the status is current.

Comment: Hi Zohar, I liked your idea. In this case, I will have to change the behavior of the program (change the logic to create a new record instead of update the current) or do you think I can do it just in the DB size (create a trigger to create a new record when update and cancel the update itself). What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: The safe way is to create an `instead of update` trigger. This way you ensure that even if the records was handled directly from SSMS it will still not be updated (except for the status column) and a new record will be inserted.

Comment: My boss did not liked the idea of the identity column because of the necessary changes in the ERP side - to show just the current records. However, you make me think about the pain that I'd get by my idea, so I'm voting your answer as the correct one. Thank you (:
Ps.: I'll just create a mirror table with both fields.